# How can I deploy a Google Cloud Function which uses a tgz file as a dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-functions

For reasons that aren't worth getting into, I need to update an existing Google Cloud Function running Node 10 to use a local tgz file as one of its dependencies (generated via `npm pack`; works locally). When I try including the archive file and the updated package.json in my Cloud Function deployment, I'm met with the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build
>   failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
>   "errorMessage": "`npm_install` had stderr output:\nnpm ERR! cb() never
>   called!\n\nnpm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report
>   this error at:\nnpm ERR!     https://npm.community\n\nnpm ERR! A
>   complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!
>   /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2019-04-08T16_01_08_142Z-debug.log\nnpm ERR!
>   code ELIFECYCLE\nnpm ERR! errno 1\nnpm ERR! @ preinstall: `npm
>   --prefix functions install`\nnpm ERR! Exit status 1\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Failed at the @ preinstall script.\nnpm ERR! This is probably not
>   a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output
>   above.\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm
>   ERR!
>   /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2019-04-08T16_01_08_171Z-debug.log\n\nerror:
>   `npm_install` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError",
>   "errorId": "C9487FAD"}}

Unfortunately, I can't access the log file referenced in the error message. Though, I will look into filing a ticket with NPM.

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to work around this issue or if there's a different strategy I should be using when including `pack`'d dependencies in a Cloud Function.

Environment:

Node v10.14.2

NPM 6.7.0

package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "engines": {
    "node": "~10.14.2",
    "npm": "~6.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "foo": "file:foo.tgz"
    "bar": "./bar.tgz"     // I've also tried other variants
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure by now you've found a solution, but for those who are getting same error:

Do not keep **package-lock.json** in your ***functions*** folder, it shouldn't be send over to server where Cloud Functions installs npm packages itself.

Comment: Nice answer here. In my .gcloudignore I had # Restrict all with `/[!.]*` and `/.?*` but the lock file was still making it over and causing problems!